# (Swift) Putting a NSNotificationCenter observer in ViewDidLoad isn't working for my project... Where should I put it?

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter, viewdidload, swrevealviewcontroller

I'm using SWRevealController to display 3 (left, center, right) panels. Basically, the right panel is a tableview of numbers and the middle panel shows possible even divisions when a user clicks on a number. I connected a segue to the IBAction of a reusable tablecell in the right view controller which loads the MainViewController. This all works fine. The problem is that if the number can't be divided evenly it triggers a notification, which the main view controller observes on ViewDidLoad. This notification sets the alpha of a pseudo-"alert" (UIView at the bottom of screen) to 1.0 for 4 seconds, at which point it returns to 0. Unfortunately this is where the problem starts: the notification box appears for a brief second while the animation runs but when the main viewcontroller finishes animating, the alert box disappears. I have a hunch it's because the ViewDidLoad fires at this point and resets the NSNotificationOberser – if I remove the segue on Touch Up Inside and manually switch view controllers the alert-box remains present.

Can you help me think of what I'm getting wrong? Like I said, I think it's because the observer is initialized in the ViewDidLoad. Assuming this is the case, where should I initialize the observer so that this doesn't happen anymore?

---

Basically the main VC displays a calculator, the code for which runs in a Calculator.swift file. If, when the number is passed through Calculate(), there is an error, it triggers an "alert" which the main VC picks up on, then reveals the box so that the user knows. Each time Calculate() is called, it logs the user's calculation to a tableview in the RVC – idea being they can reload previous calculations. Is this an improper usage of Notification Center?

The way I want the timeline of events to be:

1. User clicks on cell in the right panel
2. Main view controller (the calculator) is pushed via segue
3. Calculate() is called on the selected number, if there is a remainder a notification is triggered
4. The main view displays the results from Calculate(), if an alert fired then it would unhide a popup box on main view.

What is currently happening:

1. User clicks on the cell in right panel
2. Calculate() is called on the number, if there is a remainder the notification fires
3. Before the main view is pushed via segue, I can see briefly in the animation the result of the trigger firing and the calculation
4. As soon as the segue animation completes the view hides

My main VC Code (PopUpView is the alert box)

```
class CalculatorVC: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "triggerAlert:", name: "alert", object: nil)
    self.PopUpView.alpha = 0.0
}
```

the triggerAlert function:

```
func triggerAlert(notification: NSNotification) {
    PopUpView.alpha = 1.0      
    let returnedRemainder = (notification.userInfo)
    let sample: Double = (returnedRemainder!["userTotal"]as! Double)
    self.label.text = "Warning! Remainder: \(Double(round(100 * sample)/100))"
}
```

the tableView didSelect of the right VC:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    newUser.calculate()

    //code here assigns the value in the selected table cell to newUser
}
```

Then in the Calculate() function:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("alert", object: nil, userInfo: userTotalDictionary)
}
```

Comment: Are you balancing `addObserver` with `removeObserver`? Do you need to listen sooner? If so, try `initWithCoder`

Comment: Hey, I've played with `removeObersver` – I can't say that I've done it correctly, I just call `deinit {  removeObersver }` – that doesn't work. If I were to do it just like this?



`init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!)
{
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
addObersver

}`


Sorry I'm new to this, I need to figure out this formatting, ha.

Comment: Can you post enough code that it can be reproduced in a local project? It sounds like the pseudo-Alert UIView is managed by the source VC and so gets hidden along with the rest of the source VC when the dest VC takes over.

Comment: I think the real problem might be that I'm using SWRevealViewController. Like I said, when I remove the segue, everything works fine. It's just that pushing the middle view controller when a cell is selected on the right side causes the popupview to hide itself.

Answer (score 4):

Notification observation/de-observation should generally be balanced between `viewDidAppear`/`viewWillDisappear` or `viewWillAppear`/`viewDidDisappear`. Either pair is usually fine, but it's wise to keep things that happen "when just offscreen" separate from things that happen "when just onscreen".

`viewDidLoad` is a poor place to set up observation, because you don't have a good place to balance removing the observation (`viewDidUnload` no longer exists). You should only remove observations in `deinit` that you set up in `init`, and view controllers really should never be observing things when they are not on screen.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, changing the add/remove observers to viewWillAppear/DidDisappear didn't help, but I'm glad to have learned about a better practice! Do you think my usage of NSNotificationCenter is improper?

Comment: It feels like you are trying to have an off-screen view controller (or a view controller possibly in the middle of a segue) manage your alert. If I'm understanding correctly, then yeah, that's wrong. View controllers should manage their views while onscreen only. It's hard to envision quite what you've done, but I suspect what you really want is a separate alert controller that manages its own UIWindow on top of the main window. It shouldn't matter what is going on in the main window then. The alert can always display. Possible I misunderstand the architecture though.

Comment: This would the timeline of the order of things I want to happen: 

1) User clicks on cell in the right panel
2) Main view controller (the calculator) is pushed via segue
3) Calculate() is called on the selected mumber, if there is a remainder a notification is triggered
4) the main view displays the results, if an alert fired then it would unhide a popup box

Comment: What is currently happening is this: 

1) user clicks on the cell in right panel
2) Calculate() is called on the number, if there is a remainder the notification fires
3) Before the main view is pushed via segue, I can see briefly in the animation the result of the trigger firing and the calculation
4) as soon as the segue animation completes the screen goes blank

Comment: there are a lot of moving parts here. As @basezen suggests, I'd try to bring this down to a small sample that you can test alone or could post. It feels like a misuse of notifications (delegation may be better here) and may be a violation of MVC (the view controllers should not hold the data themselves. That should be in the model.) but it's challenging to do remote design work this way. Sorry I can't be of greater help, but try to simplify it to a smaller test case.